# Include a GitHub submodule automatically in download

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I have a GitHub repository and use another project as a submodule. This submodule is also in `.gitmodules`, the code below:

```
[submodule "inc/tha"]
    path = inc/tha
    url = git://github.com/zamoose/themehookalliance.git
```

See also in view on GitHub.

[image: submodule in repo]

How is it possible to download my GitHub repository, including the submodule files?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This (include the submodule with a GitHub zip or tarball download: the [Nodeload service](https://github.com/blog/1089-nodeload-metrics)) isn't currently supported, as mentioned in [this thread](https://github.com/wbond/sublime_package_control/issues/126#issuecomment-5470380).

[This script revision](https://github.com/quarnster/sublime_package_control/commit/9fe2fc2cad9bd2e7e1a38d7e5d4aaa02fb2b4aea) would make the zip itself from a GitHub repo, *including* submodules, through multiple calls to https://nodeload.github.com/user/repo/zipball/branch.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; pity, that github has no solution.

Comment: @bueltge true, but at least the `sublime_package_control` project offers you a way to get *everything* for a given repo.

Comment: Yes, I have read them, but is pythen and is not my current language, maybe later and current only on the wishlist.

Comment: @bueltge I understand, but the idea is there: parsing the `.gitmodules` file and calling https://nodeload.github.com/user/repo/zipball/branch for each modules declared there. That could be adapted in any script language.

Comment: This is a fine idea. I will see forward for this solution to include this. Maybe the project have a documentation in different language or a template in python for easy to use.

Comment: This answer is correct and all, but I'd like to get an explanation on how to actually implement this solution? Do I have to run this python script locally or is there something that can be done with the github repo?

Comment: @Birger It is meant to be run locally, in order to complete the zip of the main repo.

Comment: From what I have observed, real submodule-uninitialized Git repos have a file at the path that should be the submodule directory, with the submodule's SHA in the file. Therefore `git submodule update --init --recursive` is not necessarily the latest commit in the branch. However this information is not included in the GitHub zipball download

Comment: After additional research, this seems to be only possible with an additional call to the GitHub Contents API, which the `"sha"` returns the submodule commit. See also https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#response-if-content-is-a-submodule

Comment: @PEMapModder "real submodule-uninitialized Git repos have a file at the path that should be the submodule directory, with the submodule's SHA in the file": correct. The gitlink (http://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309, http://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309) is not, I suspect, present in the archive though. Meaning you cannot know the exact SHA1 unless you are using the GitHub Content API you mention.

Comment: For others' reference: I used [this method](https://github.com/poggit/poggit/blob/cf1aef414deaa922f8faf56bb1c9ed5fd8d7e931/src/poggit/builder/RepoZipball.php) to imitate a virtual filesystem with recursive cloning.