# Are the commit IDs of submodules kept in a git tag?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, git-tag

The impetus behind this is to manage both the source and wiki repositories of GitHub and be able to `git tag` the state of the entire project for releases.  If there is an easier way to go about this, I'm all ears in the comments :)

---

I need to be able to include some sort of identifier for the state of a submodule (as returned be `git submodule status`, for example) in the tag.  I don't *really* need to be able to package it *all* up (as in [Include a GitHub submodule automatically in download](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12936014/1443496))—I only *need* the ability to include this identifier—but any additional functionality available to me is *awesome*.

As an aside, I'm surprised this isn't kept track of in `.gitmodules`.  I understand it's somewhere in `.git`, but it doesn't seem to be the case that any information therein is tracked (it makes sense for it not to be).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commit id associated with the submodule is stored as a `commit` object in the `tree` object for the directory containing the submodule.  For example, I have [packstack](https://github.com/stackforge/packstack) checked out locally which has a number of submodules in `packstack/puppet/modules`; we can see the commits like this:

```
$ git ls-tree HEAD | awk '/packstack/ {print $3}'
e7f8ff02ee9ceb26df165439fdffdad13e7ffe63
$ git ls-tree e7f8ff02ee9ceb26df165439fdffdad13e7ffe63 | awk '/puppet/ {print $3}'
0f710acfee985c3f8c3e559425a76194a4a809ea
$ git ls-tree 0f710acfee985c3f8c3e559425a76194a4a809ea | awk '/modules/ {print $3}'
1ccbe1d23c3ae2f2fe6aab987dd8d84d634012ef
$ git ls-tree 1ccbe1d23c3ae2f2fe6aab987dd8d84d634012ef
160000 commit 6d2dc044e12c4c687647cff8bc60c981d9ed5312  heat
160000 commit 17ba6a73cec7f386922e6a914a120a829e225efc  horizon
160000 commit fe9b0d5229ea37179a08c4b49239da9bc950acd1  inifile
160000 commit bb67ef3e0a7c605cee97f9a8ccd13000290f9b39  keystone
.
.
.
```

And of course you can see the commit ids for previous versions of your repository by starting somewhere other than `HEAD`.